# Not able to move file from one folder to other in WPF C#

Tags: wpf, file

I have simple wpf application where I am trying to move a file from one folder to other folder. My file is `RTC.hex` is on desktop. I am trying to move it to a folder in D drive. Code:

```
    private void Move_ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
        if (result == true)

        {

            string filename = dlg.SafeFileName;

            System.IO.File.Move(filename, @"D:\New Folder\" + filename);

        }


    }
```

but it shows following error:

[image]

What wrong I am doing here.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the FileDialog's `FileName` property instead of `SafeFileName`, because it contains a full path:

```
string filename = dlg.FileName;
```

From the [`SafeFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.filedialog.safefilename(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN:

> This value is the FileName with all path information removed.

You also have to create the target folder, before you can write to it.

```
var targetDir = @"D:\New Folder";

System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetDir);
System.IO.File.Move(filename,
    System.IO.Path.Combine(targetDir, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename)));
```

Comment: Yes tried with that too. but now it shows `could not find part of the path D:\\New Folder\\ ` but the path is correct.

Comment: Ok it works but I didnt get it. Why we need to create folder before moving the file. Is it necessary.?

Comment: Yes, obviously.

Comment: This means that everytime I want to move a file, I'll have to create that directory which is already created.

Comment: Of course not if it's already there, but CreateDirectory silently ignores this. You may of course check if it exists beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Which value is on running time in your filename variable?
Their should be the path to your desktop folder (C:/Users//Desktop) + 'RTC.hex'.
(For Windows 7 and 8)

The desktop path could be different for older Windows OS.